# Sqlbase 7 server .uld Files

Tags: oracle, oledb, sqlbase

I have a backup files for Db and ibwant to open them vit unfortunately my license for sqlbase 7 server is not valid so is there is a way to open those files or convert them to any file type to use it . the files have .uld extension

Answer (score 0):

.uld files are simply unloaded text files created using the UNLOAD utility in SQLTalk and should be just text files you can open with notepad. You don't need to convert them to anything.
If you can't open them with notepad - they're not true .uld and must have been renamed.

True backup files are .bkp, and are binary format - a totally different scenario.